# Why "se + verb + article + noun" in some cases, but not in other cases?

Tags: verbos, sustantivos, reflexivos

I've learned that the following expressions are correct:

> Se lava la mano. (She washes her hands.)
>   Lavó su ropa. (She washed her clothes.)

But a few search results suggest that the following are wrong:

> Lava su mano. (Wrong)
>   Se lava la ropa. (Wrong)
>   Se olvidó los libros. (She forgot her books, but it's *wrong*)

I don't quite see any difference here but it looks like a clear-cut, so

When is "reflexive verb + article" required? When is it forbidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your examples are grammatically and semantically correct, you can use both versions:

- Lava su mano: not as common as "se lava la mano"
- Se lava la ropa / Lavó su ropa: both versions are perfectly correct. The first one stresses in my opinion the fact that he washes his own clothes.
- Se olvidó los libros / Olvidó los libros: both versions are correct

But you are right : there are some verbs which are reflexive. There are even some verbs which have different meanings, whether you use them as reflexive verbs or not. For example:

- Llamar (ella llama a su madre / she calls her mom) , llamarse (ella se llama Pilar / her name is Pilar)
- Ir (él va al trabajo / he goes to work) , irse (se acaba de ir / he is just gone)

and many more, you can google for them or take a look [here](https://espanol.lingolia.com/en/grammar/verbs/reflexive-verbs).

I am afraid you will have to learn by heart which verbs with which meaning are reflexive. There is no general rule for this in Spanish.

There is also a special case (or maybe the common case?) when  someone is performing an action on themselves. In this case you use a reflexive construction like the examples you mentioned

Comment: I think you (partially) misunderstood me. I've been told that *he washes his hand* must be translated into *se lava la mano* instead of using possessive pronouns like *mi*, *tu*, *nuestro* and *su*, which is what I'm asking about.

Comment: "Se lava su mano", "Lava su mano" and "Se lava la mano" are all correct and not uncommon to be heard in Spain.